# I use Python Flask and javascript to build a line chart, but it is not working although I can see the values are present in chrome inspect elements

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, linechart

I am trying to build a line chart by using python Flask and HTML. Here is my HTML scripts

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    
    <canvas id="lineChart" width="900" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
        var lineChart = new Chart (ctx, {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                labels: {{ labels | safe }}
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Room 1 Temperature",
                        data: {{ values | safe }},
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
                        lineTension: 0.1
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: false
            }
        });
    </script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the python scripts:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test')
def test():
  data = [
    ("a", 70),
    ("b", 50),
    ("c", 10),
    ("d", 60),
    ("e", 50),
    ("a", 90),
  ]

labels = [row[0] for row in data]
values = [row[1] for row in data]

return render_template('test.html', labels=labels, values=values)
```

the problem is it displays nothing when I run it, but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2hytuQvLlE) use case is working fine.

What makes me even more confuse is, I can see the *labels* and *values* variables are already present in html when I troubleshoot in chrome.

Can anyone tell me what I did it wrongly? Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to add comma after labels.

[image]

Comment: dang!! I hate myself. Thanks @raggsss